# FreeRTOS: two tasks with interrupt

Tags: freertos

I'm completely new with FreeRTOS. I have two tasks: the first one must be performed continuously in the loop and the second one should turn on only after interrupt and after the second one is done it should return to the first one, which needs to start from the beginning(it's important because the first task collects data and if I continue to perform it from the place where I interrupt I will get the trash.).

Can I use Semaphore for it or is there something better? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking or what you want to use the semaphore for.  Protecting data access by both the interrupt and the first task?  Or maybe signaling the first task?  From what I can make out it sounds like you want to have a lower priority task running continuously, then when an interrupt occurs have the interrupt handler unblock a higher priority task that will then preempt the lower priority task and execute.  Then when it finishes and blocks again the scheduler will naturally continue running the lower priority task.  I'm confused by your statement that if you continue executing from where it was interrupted you will get trash though - interrupts always return to where they interrupted.

The most efficient way of unblocking a task from an interrupt would be a [direct-to-task notification](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS_Task_Notification_As_Counting_Semaphore.html).  I would also recommend reading some of the generic FreeRTOS documentation and books available on the FreeRTOS.org site.